How to get rid of the space in between name of the function and the parenthesis e.g. in $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?
I want to get rid of the space between name of the function and the parenthesis argument as in $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.
This space feels unnatural to me. I know a solution to get around this but I am not satisfied with it.
\DeclareMathOperator{\f}{f}
\f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)

This renders $\DeclareMathOperator{\f}{f}\f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. Notice the space is removed but $f$ is changed to $\f$.
How to get rid of the space while maintaining the $f$ in this font?
I am not nitpick; I don't want to use $f$ in a different font to keep my answers consistent with original posts.

This is a "fussy spacing issue", and should have been covered in the MathJax guide.  I have added it to this answer.

I don't understand the downvotes... My question isn't opinion based, so what's the disagreement? IMO, it's an important question and it was not covered in the MathJax guide at the time I posted this...

Just a guess, probably some users don't feel the extra space as a problem and hence they don't agree to your proposal.

You may try the negative spacing operator \!  like $f\! \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ to get $f\! \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.
However I think the extra space is due to left right commands and they are needed to resize the parentheses based on their argument. Without left right like $f(x) $ we get $f(x) $.

$$
f(x)
$$
$$
f(\frac1{x})
$$
$$
f\left(\frac1{x}\right)
$$
$$
f\LARGE{(\small{\frac1{x}}\Large)}
$$
$$
\vcenter{\Large{f}}\Huge{({\vcenter{\small{\frac1{x}}}}\Huge)}
$$
$$
f(\frac1{x})
$$
$$
f\left(\frac1{x}\right)
$$
$$
f\LARGE{(\small{\frac1{x}}\Large)}
$$
$$
\vcenter{\Large{f}}\Huge{({\vcenter{\small{\frac1{x}}}}\Huge)}
$$

Also, see the Stack Exchange Meta article:
"Changing mathjax's font size"

I don't understand the inconsistent use of \Large. That looks even worse.

@Nothingspecial:  Click on the link to Changing mathjax's font size.  The strategy is to recognize that simple parenthesis like $f(x)$ do not have extra space.  But for $f(\frac1{x})$, the only difficulty is that the parenthesis are too small.  So, following the link, the parenthesis size is adjusted using \LARGE{(...)} as $\LARGE{(...)}$ . From the link, the could be increased even more  using \Huge(...)} as in $\Huge{(...)}$.  But then the inside fraction needs to be set small so it fits.

The inside fraction does not need to be set small to fit, e.g. \Large f\!\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) is typeset as $$\Large f!\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$  Or write \Large f\!\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right) to get $$\Large f!\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right).$$
